# Not able to get graphs on screen with gnuplot

Tags: drivers

I have installed 12.04 along with Windows 7 and also installed **gnuplot 4.6.0**.

When I type `gnuplot` on the terminal, I am getting the error message:

```
Terminal type set to unknown.
```

When I tried `plot sin(x)`, the graph does not appear on the screen.

However, I am able to make a postscript file. I tried `set terminal 'x11'`, system responds with:

```
unknown or ambiguous terminal.
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Is this on Windows or Ubuntu? Strange that the x11 term is not there. Have you tried typing "set term" to get a list of installed terminals?

Comment: This post solved the problem for me: 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/217867/just-installed-ubuntu-12-10-and-gnuplot-wxt-terminal-doesnt-work

Answer (score 9):

Jotrocken's comment was spot on -- copying from the answer he linked to:

Just add `gnuplot-x11` package via the terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install gnuplot-x11
```

or via the software-center:

[image: Install via the software center]

It solved my plotting problems for GNUPlot in Octave!!!

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit.  When gnuplot starts up, there's no default terminal type ("Terminal type set to 'unknown'").  If I then do

```
set term xterm
```

which is in the list returned by

```
set term
```

and then try to plot **any** function, all I get is gobbledygook.  I've tried uninstalling gnuplot *completely* (via apt-get purge) from my computer and installing only gnuplot-x11, and doing a manual install from the gnuplot-4.6.0 package using the ./configure --with-x option with success.  The only "solution" I've found is to use

```
set term dumb
```

and put up with a text-based graphic.  This is ok for just checking the shape of a simple function.  For more complicated functions, I've resorted to using the epslatex terminal and gv to view the output.

Is there anyone out there who's found a better and more complete solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have succeed in installing `gnuplot` after installing the following libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libxt-dev libreadline-gplv2-dev glib-2.0
```

Using the first 3 allowed to use `gnuplot`. After installing `glib-2.0` allowed me plot in a x11 terminal.

Answer (score 0):

xterm will be good for a while, but if you require GNU octave too, then you certainly require gnuplot to detect x11 terminal. There are two ways which I hope must resolve it for you:

1. Edit configure script in the .gz downloaded from gnuplot site to meet some positive value in X11_APPDEFAULTS_DIR variable.
2. You could just do `apt-get install glib-2.0` and configure the the gnuplot again. This time it DOES detect your terminal.

Hope this helps. I myself have had to give it hours.