# Just installed Ubuntu 12.10 and Gnuplot wxt terminal doesn't work

Tags: 12.10

I've just installed the latest version of Ubuntu (12.10).  I then installed Gnuplot with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnuplot
```

However, now whenever I run Gnuplot it says

```
terminal set to 'unknown'
```

On my old installation of Ubuntu (12.04) it worked and would set the terminal to 'wxt'.

Any idea why it doesn't set it to the correct terminal?

Also,`set terminal wxt` doesn't work either.

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just add `gnuplot-x11` package via the terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install gnuplot-x11
```

or via the software-center:

[image: Install via the software center]