# cannot plot graph in gnuplot-x11

Tags: gnuplot

I am using gnuplot under ubuntu 12.04. When i type in terminal :

```
Terminal Type Set to 'unknown'
gnuplot> plot sin(x)
```

it only shows next step:

```
gnuplot>
```

but it doesn't show the graph plotting windows. What can I do to find the problem?
I have already installed gnuplot-x11. It is showing that the latest version is installed.

Comment: Does it create a PNG file if you `set terminal png` and `set output filename.png'?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that "unknown".

Here says the same as you said you have, install `gnuplot-x11` : [Not able to get graphs on screen with gnuplot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171778/not-able-to-get-graphs-on-screen-with-gnuplot)

Maybe trying to do a reconfiguration of the package?

```
sudo apt-get purge gnuplot*
sudo apt-get install gnuplot-x11
```

Comment: ...and removing `$HOME/.gnuplot*` files could help. He/She may have some strange configuration there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200463/gnuplot-configuration-file

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling gnuplot-nox.

```
sudo apt-get purge gnuplot-nox
```

It works for me and automatically installed gnuplot-x11 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0.

Comment: This may be a valid answer (I don't know.), but it could use a bit more detail. How do you know that the nox version is installed? Will the plot command "just work" as is once nox is removed? Usually, uninstalling one package doesn't ensure that another version will automatically replace it unless removing/purging it leaves unmet dependencies.